# Encoding duplicate characters of a string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary, replace, character-encoding

I am trying to encode a string to replace a character with '(' if it occurs only once and with ')' if it occurs more than once. So "hello" becomes "(())(". I am using dictionary to solve this.  I am saving the number of occurrences of each character in the string . Then I check if that character comes up more than once then I use .replace() to replace it with ')' else with '('. The problem happens when the string contains ')'.

So for example if I have the string "abca)". I should get ")(())" as the result but I get "(((((" cause when the program gets to ')' it sees it has occurred only once and then changes every occurrence of ')' with '('. It works fine rest of the time. Here's my code:

```
def duplicate_encode(word):
    count = {}
    word = word.lower()
    for ch in word:
        if ch in count:
            count[ch] += 1
        else:
            count[ch] = 1
    for k in count:
        if count[k] > 1:
            word = word.replace(k, ')')
        else:
            word = word.replace(k, '(')
    print(word)


duplicate_encode("abca)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code it will work

```
A=input()
b=list(A)
c=list(set(A))
for i in c:
    if b.count(i)>1:
        A=A.replace(i,")")
    elif b.count(i)==1:
        A=A.replace(i,"(")
print(A)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand now that it's better to compare from another list (like b and c in your code) than to compare from a lone list (like I was using the dictionary) cause the dictionary was causing the interpreter to check all the occurrences of the character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your code:

- the only (and trailing) `(` in `word` causes final `word = replace(word, '(', ')')` so  that *all* `(`s are replaced with `)`s; therefore, I build the  `outword` string from scratch;
- `len(count) < len(word)` if there is any duplicate character in `word`; therefore, the `k` must iterate over `word` rather than over `count`.

Fixed code:

```
def duplicate_encode(word):
    count = {}
    outword = ''
    word = word.lower()
    for ch in word:
        if ch in count:
            count[ch] += 1
        else:
            count[ch] = 1
    for k in word:
        if count[k] > 1:
            outword += ')'
        else:
            outword += '('
    print( word, '=>', outword )

duplicate_encode("abca)")
duplicate_encode("hello")
```

**Output**: `.\SO\67089558.py`

```
abca) => )(()(
hello => (())(
```

Comment: `outword = ''.join( [')' if count[k] > 1 else '(' for k in word])` is more _pythonish_ version of the `for k in word:` loop…

Comment: Thanks Josef! I see now my mistake that I was iterating over `count` rather than `word` and missing the the point that `count` is shorter in length if there are repeating characters. Thanks for the _pythonish_ version as well.